# Can't access value from an array inside JSON object in Reactjs

Tags: arrays, reactjs

I have this state defined:

```
 constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            open: false,
            customers:[],
            customer:{},
            products:[],
            product:{},
            orders:[],
            order:{},
            newForm:true,
            phoneNumbererror:null,
            shop:this.props.salon,
            value:'a',
            showTab:'none',
            slideIndex: 0,

        };
    }
```

With the following function which contains a fetch, I recieve an array of objects with responseData.

```
getHistory(){
        console.log("Log antes del fetch de customer id");
        console.log(this.state.customer._id);
        fetch(
            DOMAIN+'/api/orders/customer/'+this.state.customer._id, {
                method: 'get',
                dataType: 'json',
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Authorization':'Bearer '+this.props.token
                }
            })
            .then((response) =>
            {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then((responseData) => {
                this.setState({orders:responseData})
                console.log("Log del responseData");
                console.log(responseData);

            })
            .catch(function() {
                console.log("error");
            });
    }
```

This function is called in `handleCellClick`, where I pass some data from the consumer, such as the ID:

```
handleCellClick(y,x,row){
        this.setState({
            open:true,
            slideIndex: 0,
            newForm:false,
            customer:{...row}
        });
        this.getProfiles();
        this.getHistory();

    }
```

The JSON object obtained from the fetch and keep it within `this.state.orders` looks like this:

```
(29) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0:
created:"2017-07-06T15:58:07.958Z"
customer:"59561f3f1d178e1966142ad7"
lastModified:"2017-07-06T15:58:07.958Z"
orderList:[]
orderStatusChange:Array(1)
0:{status: "5", comments: "Creado en back antes de pagar", _id: "595e5e0f60fbf65149916b7c", created: "2017-07-06T15:58:07.958Z"}
length:1
__proto__:Array(0)
shop:"59108159bc3fc645704ba508"
totalAmount:4000
__v:0
_id:"595e5e0f60fbf65149916b7b"
__proto__:Object
```

Capture of the object for better understanding: [CAPTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6IrMC.png)

As shown previously in the fetch, with this line `this.setState({orders:responseData})` I can pass `orders` to the table where I want the id, the date and status to be displayed:

```
<DataTables
     height={'auto'}
     selectable={false}
     showRowHover={true}
     columns={HISTORY_TABLE_COLUMNS}
     data={this.state.orders}
     showCheckboxes={false}
     rowSizeLabel="Filas por página"
         />
```

The table called is:

```
const HISTORY_TABLE_COLUMNS = [
    {
        key: '_id',
        label: 'Número de pedido'
    }, {
        key: 'created',
        label: 'Fecha del pedido'
    }, {
        key: 'status',
        label: 'Estado'
    }
];
```

The problem comes to, when I want to print `_id`, `created` and `status`, the first two values are printed without any problem, but `status`is within the array `orderStatusChange`, and I can't print it.

[CAPTURE OF THE CURRENT SITUATION](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6P3cd.png)

**How can I access `status` to print it on the table?**

Comment: How do you access `status` from the `state.orders`?

Comment: Is array orderStatusChange of length 1 always ?

Comment: Now i just put the key `status `on the table (which doesn't work), but works fine with `_id ` and `created`.

Comment: @Dev No, it isn't. It depends on the number of orders from the client.

Comment: So as you said, how should status be displayed for order. i mean comma seperated ? As one order would have multiple status as shown in data

Comment: can you provide the link of `DataTables` lib that you are using?

Comment: @Dev Oh, I misunderstood your question. orderStatusChange is always length 1, because an order just can have one status at a time.

Comment: @MayankShukla https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-ui-datatables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you find some option/props available in DataTable to display what you are trying, please use that.**

> This may sound the crude way to achieve what you are trying. But this should work. Please update below promise callback.

```
.then((responseData) => {
    let orders = responseData.map((order) => {
       return order.orderStatusChange ? Object.assign({}, order, {
         status: order.orderStatusChange[0].status
       }) : order;
     })
    this.setState({orders:orders})
})
```

> In the above snippet, I am checking if the order has the key 'orderStatusChange' and it will take the status from first record and return a new object with status or else it will return the original order object.

Comment: This will return me the same status for every order, what if I want to change the status depending on the order [0],[1],[2]...

Comment: Each order would have orderStatusChange array of length 1. It will take the status from the first record if orderStatusChange is present or else it will not show any status.

Comment: Ahh, now I understand what you've made and you are right! Thanks for your time and effort.

Answer (score 1):

As per DOC:

**[Column settings:](https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-ui-datatables#column-settings)**

```
key         :  string       
label       :  string       
sortable    :  bool     
tooltip     :  string       
className   :  string       
render      :  function       //here
alignRight  :  bool     
style       :  object
```

There is a column property `render`, its a function, use that to return some custom element, like this:

```
const HISTORY_TABLE_COLUMNS = [
    {
        ....
    }, {
        ....
    }, {
        key: 'orderStatusChange',
        label: 'Estado'
        render: (staorderStatusChangetus, all) => {
            /*
               check the console values  
               i am expecting all will have the each object of the array, and 
               orderStatusChange will have that orderStatusChange array
               so you can return the result of:
               orderStatusChange.map(el => <p>{el.status}</p>)
            */ 
            console.log('value', status, all);
            return orderStatusChange.map(el => <p>{el.status}</p>)
        }
    }
];
```

**Note:** Not sure about the values so check the console output and return the result that you want.

Comment: I think that the solution could be something like this since `orderStatusChange` will have only one element: `render: (orderStatusChange, all) => <p>{orderStatusChange[0].status}</p>`

Comment: @CésarLandesa how do i get to know that it will contain only one value :), i provide a generic solution that will work for any no of array elements, if that array contains one value then you can write in that way also :)

Comment: Calicorio2 said so in a comment! :) That's how I know ;)